# Change a json/javascript object var name or retrieve values from a numerical var

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've some page that gives me kinda of a JSON file/output like this
example:

- Description:

  - 23463232

    - tags
    - appid
  - 35433523

    - tags
    - appid
  - 12345234

    - tags
    - appid

I'm trying to get the tags values, like so `description.23463232.tags`

Add gives me this error:

> SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

---

I know that you all vars must be strings started by letters but I can't change that because this file/page is not mine. So, I'd like to know what can I do to retrieve the tags values or if there is some way to change the name of that vars like "23463232" to something else.

Comment: description['23463232'].tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use property accessor to access any property name:
`description["23463232"].tags`

Just for completeness of the answer, if you still need to change the variables, you can do this:

```
for(var key in description) {
    var value = description[key];
    //copy the value to a new key (_ prepended) then delete the original key.
    description["_"+key] = value;
    delete description[key];
}
```

Now you can access the values like: `description._23463232.tags`

Comment: The stated reason is misleading. As *per JavaScript, 'bare properties' must be valid identifiers*. In this case that is not possible (as `1234` is a number, not an identifier) so the alternate form has to be used. The JSON format itself is irrelevant for fixing the JavaScript syntax.

Comment: As stated in the question, the json is coming from server and it's not an object literal in javascript. You can use number as property name in javascript but in JSON (serialized as string) it will always be string. I mentioned that since it matters how you access the property description[123] or description["123"]

Comment: So since it's not JavaScript (which is *where* the error is), it's a misleading intro reason. The error is simple: `1234` is *not* a valid JavaScript identifier. The `obj.prop` form requires that `prop` *is* a valid JavaScript identifier while `obj[x]` allows `x` to be any valid JavaScript expression. Nothing inherently to do with strings (and `description[23463232]` is also valid), just syntax.

Answer (score 4):

That number *is* probably a string. You can try using the square bracket syntax for reading JSON like so: `description["23463232"]["tags"]`

Comment: The number *is* a string in JSON and the JS property name *is* equivalent to the same string value.. the square brackets have naught to do with string vs. non-string; but rather a sequence of numbers is not a valid JavaScript identifier. Both `description["23463232"]` and `description[23463232]` would work.